# Handling Hidden Buttons and Button text using JSON response in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I get the following json response from my webservice.

```
{
"error": "false",
"subjects": [
    {
        "subject": "Subject One"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Subject Two"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Subject Three"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Subject Four"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Subject Five"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Subject Six"
    }
]
}
```

I am calling this service in ViewController.m which has 8 hidden buttons. I would like to enable buttons and set the text for these buttons based on this response. In the example above, I am receiving six subjects so I would like to enable/show 6 buttons and set their text to Subject One , Subject 2 and so on.

I am using Objective C for implementation.

Currently, I am using the following lines of code to get the JSON response and store it in an array

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"subjects"]];
```

Can someone please guide me on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar to this in my projects. You can enumerate through the your JSON array like this:

```
[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

//Each one of your subject in "Subjects" is probably a dictionary
//So using the below code you'll get the "Subject One" "Subject Two" and so on.
    NSString *title = obj[@"subject"];
//title should be something like Subject One

//Then, make sure that it exists.
    if (title) {

    //If so, get the correct button from the enumerate idk and set hidden NO and text = title
        UIButton *button = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:idx];
        button.hidden = NO;
        button.text = title;
    }

}];
```

This may change slightly depending on the JSON. But in my app this code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Interface Builder** to setup your User Interface and placing the UIButtons and setting them to **hidden** within your **Storyboard**.

With these steps, you should be able to display each UIButton that is represented by your JSON response:

1. Place your **UIButton**s within your View Controller and setup the constraints that will correctly position each button.
2. Connect (ctrl drag) your IBActions to the **UIViewController**s header (.h) file.
3. After connecting the IBActions for each UIButton, connect (ctrl drag again) each button to the header file (or header extension in the implementation file), but set it as an **IBOutlet** with a **weak** reference.

   a. Check to be sure the placements are correct before hiding.
4. Once you've placed the buttons where you're wanting and they are displaying properly, go back to Interface Builder and *tick* UIButton's **Hidden** property.
5. Also, *untick* each UIButton's **User Interaction Enabled** property.
6. **NOW** compare your JSON response array using a **For Loop** and for each of the UIButtons you'll need, access the corresponding (weak) reference in the header file and change the properties you've updated previously.

Code Example to change each UIButton back from hidden and user interaction enabled:

```
_buttonOne.hidden = NO;
_buttonOne.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Each instance you'll need should be placed in your for loop so they respond to the corresponding **response** in your local JSON array.

Hope this helps!